# neural network does not learn (loss stays the same)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

My project partner and I are currently facing a problem in our latest university project.
Our mission is to implement a neural network that plays the game Pong. We are giving the ball position the ball speed and the position of the paddles to our network and have three outputs: UP DOWN DO_NOTHING. After a player has 11 points we train the network with all states, the made decisions and the reward of the made decisions (see reward_cal()). The problem we are facing is, that the loss is constantly staying at a specific value only depending on the learning rate. Because of this the network always makes the same decision even though we reward it as terribly wrong.

Please help us find out what we did wrong we are thankful for every advise! Below is our code pls feel free to ask if there are any questions. We are pretty new to this topic so pls don't be rude if there is something completly stupid :D

this is our code:

```
import sys, pygame, time
import numpy as np
import random
from os.path import isfile
import keras
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.core import Flatten


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

#surface of the game
width = 400
height = 600
black = 0, 0, 0 #RGB value
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32)
#(Resolution(x,y), flags, colour depth)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36, bold=True)
pygame.display.set_caption('PyPong') #title of window

#consts for the game
acceleration = 0.0025 # ball becomes faster during the game
mousematch = 1
delay_time = 0
paddleP = pygame.image.load("schlaeger.gif")
playerRect = paddleP.get_rect(center = (200, 550))
paddleC = pygame.image.load("schlaeger.gif")
comRect = paddleC.get_rect(center=(200,50))
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.gif")
ballRect = ball.get_rect(center=(200,300))

#Variables for the game
pointsPlayer = [0]
pointsCom = [0]
playermove = [0, 0]
speedbar = [0, 0]
speed = [6, 6]
hitX = 0

#neural const
learning_rate = 0.01
number_of_actions = 3
filehandler = open('logfile.log', 'a')
filename = sys.argv[1]

#neural variables
states, action_prob_grads, rewards, action_probs = [], [], [], []

reward_sum = 0
episode_number = 0
reward_sums = []




pygame.display.flip()


def pointcontrol(): #having a look at the points in the game and restart()
     if pointsPlayer[0] >= 11:
        print('Player Won ', pointsPlayer[0], '/', pointsCom[0])
        restart(1)
        return 1
     if pointsCom[0] >= 11:
        print('Computer Won ', pointsPlayer[0], '/', pointsCom[0])
        restart(1)
        return 1
     elif pointsCom[0] < 11 and pointsPlayer[0] < 11:
        restart(0)
        return 0

def restart(finished): #resetting the positions and the ball speed and
(if point limit was reached) the points
     ballRect.center = 200,300
     comRect.center = 200,50
     playerRect.center = 200, 550
     speed[0] = 6
     speed[1] = 6
     screen.blit(paddleC, comRect)
     screen.blit(paddleP, playerRect)
     pygame.display.flip()
     if finished:
         pointsPlayer[0] = 0
         pointsCom[0] = 0

def reward_cal(r, gamma = 0.99): #rewarding every move
     discounted_r = np.zeros_like(r) #making zero array with size of
reward array
     running_add = 0
     for t in range(r.size - 1, 0, -1): #iterating beginning in the end
         if r[t] != 0: #if reward -1 or 1 (point made or lost)
             running_add = 0
         running_add = running_add * gamma + r[t] #making every move
before the point the same reward but a little bit smaller
         discounted_r[t] = running_add #putting the value in the new
reward array
     #e.g r = 000001000-1 -> discounted_r = 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 -0.7
-0.8 -0.9 -1 values are not really correct just to make it clear
     return discounted_r


#neural net
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = (8), kernel_initializer =
'glorot_normal', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal', activation =
'relu'))
model.add(Dense(number_of_actions, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam')
model.summary()

if isfile(filename):
     model.load_weights(filename)

# one ball movement before the AI gets to make a decision
ballRect = ballRect.move(speed)
reward_temp = 0.0
if ballRect.left < 0 or ballRect.right > width:
    speed[0] = -speed[0]
if ballRect.top < 0:
    pointsPlayer[0] += 1
    reward_temp = 1.0
    done = pointcontrol()
if ballRect.bottom > height:
    pointsCom[0] += 1
    done = pointcontrol()
    reward_temp = -1.0
if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect):
    speed[1] = -speed[1]
if ballRect.colliderect(comRect):
    speed[1] = -speed[1]
if speed[0] < 0:
    speed[0] -= acceleration
if speed[0] > 0:
    speed[0] += acceleration
if speed[1] < 0:
    speed[1] -= acceleration
if speed[1] > 0 :
    speed[1] += acceleration

while True: #game
     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

     state = np.array([ballRect.center[0], ballRect.center[1], speed[0],
speed[1], playerRect.center[0], playerRect.center[1], comRect.center[0],
comRect.center[1]])
     states.append(state)
     action_prob = model.predict_on_batch(state.reshape(1, 8))[0, :]

     action_probs.append(action_prob)
     action = np.random.choice(number_of_actions, p=action_prob)
     if(action == 0): playermove = [0, 0]
     elif(action == 1): playermove = [5, 0]
     elif(action == 2): playermove = [-5, 0]
     playerRect = playerRect.move(playermove)

     y = np.array([-1, -1, -1])
     y[action] = 1
     action_prob_grads.append(y-action_prob)

     #enemy move
     comRect = comRect.move(speedbar)
     ballY = ballRect.left+5
     comRectY = comRect.left+30
     if comRect.top <= (height/1.5):
        if comRectY - ballY > 0:
           speedbar[0] = -7
        elif comRectY - ballY < 0:
           speedbar[0] = 7
     if comRect.top > (height/1.5):
        speedbar[0] = 0

     if(mousematch == 1):
          done = 0
          reward_temp = 0.0
          ballRect = ballRect.move(speed)
          if ballRect.left < 0 or ballRect.right > width:
                speed[0] = -speed[0]
          if ballRect.top < 0:
                pointsPlayer[0] += 1
                done = pointcontrol()
                reward_temp = 1.0
          if ballRect.bottom > height:
                pointsCom[0] += 1
                done = pointcontrol()
                reward_temp = -1.0
          if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect):
                speed[1] = -speed[1]
          if ballRect.colliderect(comRect):
                speed[1] = -speed[1]
          if speed[0] < 0:
                speed[0] -= acceleration
          if speed[0] > 0:
                speed[0] += acceleration
          if speed[1] < 0:
                speed[1] -= acceleration
          if speed[1] > 0 :
                speed[1] += acceleration
          rewards.append(reward_temp)

          if (done):
              episode_number += 1
              reward_sums.append(np.sum(rewards))
              if len(reward_sums) > 40:
                  reward_sums.pop(0)
              s = 'Episode %d Total Episode Reward: %f , Mean %f' % (
episode_number, np.sum(rewards), np.mean(reward_sums))
              print(s)
              filehandler.write(s + '\n')
              filehandler.flush()

              # Propagate the rewards back to actions where no reward
was given.
              # Rewards for earlier actions are attenuated
              rewards = np.vstack(rewards)

              action_prob_grads = np.vstack(action_prob_grads)
              rewards = reward_cal(rewards)

              X = np.vstack(states).reshape(-1, 8)

              Y = action_probs + learning_rate * rewards * y


              print('loss: ', model.train_on_batch(X, Y))

              model.save_weights(filename)

              states, action_prob_grads, rewards, action_probs = [], [], [], []

              reward_sum = 0

          screen.fill(black)
          screen.blit(paddleP, playerRect)
          screen.blit(ball, ballRect)
          screen.blit(paddleC, comRect)
          pygame.display.flip()
          pygame.time.delay(delay_time)
```

this is our output:

```
pygame 1.9.4 Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html Using TensorFlow backend.
    _________________________________________________________________ 

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    ================================================================= 

dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 16)                144       
    _________________________________________________________________ 

dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 32)                544       
    _________________________________________________________________ 

dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 99        
    ================================================================= 

Total params: 787 Trainable params: 787 Non-trainable params: 0
    _________________________________________________________________ 2019-02-14 11:18:10.543401: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA 2019-02-14 11:18:10.666634: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:  name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705 pciBusID: 0000:17:00.0 totalMemory:
    10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB 2019-02-14 11:18:10.775144: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 1 with properties:  name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705 pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0 totalMemory:
    10.91GiB freeMemory: 10.73GiB 2019-02-14 11:18:10.776037: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1 2019-02-14 11:18:11.176560: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-02-14 11:18:11.176590: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 1  2019-02-14 11:18:11.176596: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N Y  2019-02-14 11:18:11.176600: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 1:   Y N  2019-02-14 11:18:11.176914: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10403 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:17:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 2019-02-14 11:18:11.177216: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10382 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) 


Computer Won  0 / 11 Episode 1 Total Episode Reward: -11.000000 , Mean -11.000000 

loss:  0.254405 


Computer Won  0 / 11 Episode 2 Total Episode Reward: -11.000000 , Mean -11.000000 

loss:  0.254304 


Computer Won  0 / 11 Episode 3 Total Episode Reward: -11.000000 , Mean -11.000000 

loss:  0.254304 


Computer Won  0 / 11 Episode 4 Total Episode Reward: -11.000000 , Mean -11.000000 

loss:  0.254304 


Computer Won  0 / 11 Episode 5 Total Episode Reward: -11.000000 , Mean -11.000000 

loss:  0.254304 


Computer Won  0 / 11 Episode 6 Total Episode Reward: -11.000000 , Mean -11.000000 

loss:  0.254304
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's evil `'relu'` showing its power.

Relu has a "zero" region without gradients. When all your outputs get negative, Relu makes all of them equal to zero and kills backpropagation.

The easiest solution for using Relus safely is to add `BatchNormalization` layers before them:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = (8), kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(32, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(number_of_actions, activation='softmax'))
```

This will make "rougly" half of the outputs of the layer be zero and half be trainable.

Other solutions consist of controlling very well your learning rate and optimizer, which may be quite a headache for beginners.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your quick help!
Unfortunatily it doesn't work at our programm. We get following error: 

model.add(BatchNormalization())
NameError: name 'BatchNormalization' is not defined

are we missing any imports? thanks again!

Comment: you need to import it from Keras first: from keras.layers import BatchNormalization

Comment: Thank you Mark sorry for the dumb question :D it seems to work at least the loss is changing now. We'll see how it looks after some training and keep you updated!