# Accuracy no longer improving after switching to Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I recently trained a binary image classifier and ended up with a model which was around 97.8% accurate. I created this classifier by following a couple of official Tensorflow guides, namely:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification
- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

I noticed while training (on a GTX 1080) that each epoch was taking around 30 seconds to run. Further reading revealed that a better way to load data into a Tensorflow training run is by using a Dataset. So I updated my code to load the images into a dataset and then have them read by the `model.fit_generator` method.

Now when I perform my training I find that my accuracy and loss metrics are static - even with the learning rate changing automatically over time. The output looks something like this:

```
loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Given that I'm training a binary classifier an accuracy of 50% is the same as guessing, so I'm wondering if there's a problem with the way I'm providing the images, or perhaps with the size of the dataset.

My image data is split like this:

```
training/
        true/  (366 images)
        false/ (354 images)

validation/
        true/  (175 images)
        false/ (885 images)
```

I was using `ImageDataGenerator` before with various mutations being performed, therefore increasing the overall dataset. Is my problem with the size of my dataset?

The application code I'm using is as follows:

```py
import math

import tensorflow as tf
import os

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

import helpers
import settings

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

assert tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
assert tf.test.is_gpu_available()

# Collect the list of training files and process their paths.
training_dataset_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.path.join(settings.TRAINING_DIRECTORY, '*', '*.png'))
training_dataset_labelled = training_dataset_files.map(helpers.process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
training_dataset = helpers.prepare_for_training(training_dataset_labelled)

# Collect the validation files.
validation_dataset_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.path.join(settings.VALIDATION_DIRECTORY, '*', '*.png'))
validation_dataset_labelled = validation_dataset_files.map(helpers.process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
validation_dataset = helpers.prepare_for_training(validation_dataset_labelled)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # This is the first convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(settings.TARGET_IMAGE_HEIGHT, settings.TARGET_IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The second convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The third convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The fourth convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The fifth convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    # Only 1 output neuron. It will contain a value from 0-1 where 0 for 1 class ('false') and 1 for the other ('true')
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.summary()

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.1),
    metrics=['acc']
)

callbacks = [
    # EarlyStopping(patience=4),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor='val_acc',
        patience=2,
        verbose=1,
        factor=0.5,
        min_lr=0.00001
    ),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        # Path where to save the model
        filepath=settings.CHECKPOINT_FILE,
        # The two parameters below mean that we will overwrite
        # the current checkpoint if and only if
        # the `val_loss` score has improved.
        save_best_only=True,
        monitor='val_loss',
        verbose=1
    ),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
        log_dir=settings.LOG_DIRECTORY,
        histogram_freq=1
    )
]

training_dataset_length = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(training_dataset_files).numpy()
steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(training_dataset_length // settings.TRAINING_BATCH_SIZE)

validation_dataset_length = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_dataset_files).numpy()
validation_steps = math.ceil(validation_dataset_length // settings.VALIDATION_BATCH_SIZE)

history = model.fit_generator(
    training_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=20000,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    validation_steps=validation_steps,
    callbacks=callbacks,
)

model.save(settings.FULL_MODEL_FILE)
```

With `helpers.py` looking like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import settings

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE


def process_path(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '\\')
    label = parts[-2] == settings.CLASS_NAMES

    # Read the file and decode the image
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [settings.TARGET_IMAGE_HEIGHT, settings.TARGET_IMAGE_WIDTH])
    return img, label


def prepare_for_training(ds, cache=True, shuffle_buffer_size=10000):
    if cache:
        if isinstance(cache, str):
            ds = ds.cache(cache)
        else:
            ds = ds.cache()

    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)

    ds = ds.repeat()
    ds = ds.batch(settings.TRAINING_BATCH_SIZE)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

    return ds
```

A larger snippet of application output is as follows:

```
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00207: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 247ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 208/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00208: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 248ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 209/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00209: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 6s 251ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 210/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00210: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 242ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 211/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00211: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 246ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 212/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00212: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 6s 252ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 213/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00213: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 242ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 214/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00214: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 241ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 215/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00215: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 247ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 216/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00216: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 248ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 217/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00217: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 249ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 218/20000
21/22 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00218: val_loss did not improve from 7.71247
22/22 [==============================] - 5s 244ms/step - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.7125 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 219/20000
19/22 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.7125 - acc: 0.5000
```

Comment: What is your batchsize? And how does your Groundtruth look like?

Comment: Batch size for both training and validation is currently set to 32. I don't know what the ground truth is.

Comment: Could you show `helpers`?

Comment: @xenteros Sure, I've just edited the original post to include it.

Comment: @DanielSamuels please have a look at the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

There are somethings you must check.

- Try a few more times, you may have been unlucky with the 'relu' activations (if one layer goes to all zeros, you're stuck forever).
- Take a `x, y` pair from the dataset and verify that `y` is within 0 and 1 (because you're using 'sigmoid').

These two are the most troublesome and probable things.

Later you might want to check whether `x` from the dataset is within the same range you trained before (not crucial, but might change a little the performance), if the number of channels are the same, etc.

---

For the relus, there are solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688502/neural-network-does-not-learn-loss-stays-the-same/54688983#54688983).

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove all the image augmentation.
Then overfit your model on a small dataset after this include the dataset with augmentation.
Also note:
training/
        true/  (366 images)
        false/ (354 images)

validation/
        true/  (175 images)
        false/ (885 images)
Your validation dataset looks too complex to me try to add more percentage of images in training dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You should highlight what changed compare to your code when it worked well.

I hope the `process_path` function was quiet similar and so that there is not any error there (image decoding, channel management, label generation).

So if the modifications are only related to the `Dataset` API you can start by checking the generated sample:

```
batch = next(iter(training_dataset))
tf.print("Image: ", batch[0][0])
tf.print("Label: ", batch[1][0])
```

Other things that seems strange:

- a shuffle buffer of size 10000 seems to big for your +700 images
- are you sure of your `steps_per_epoch` value. Dataset cardinality is not always very accurate.